# Windows 10 wifi not turning on Acer Aspire laptop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, acer-aspire

[image: wifi settings screen]

This is fresh Windows 10 on Acer Aspire v3-571g.
After turning wifi on in settings (the upper part of the screenshot) Windows still shows that wifi is off (the bottom right corner). Clicking on `Show available networks` does not do anything.

What can cause this problem?

UPD: When I click on `Network settings` in the right bottom corner, the Settings window updates, and it has wifi switcher on Off. I can switch it to On, but after clicking on `Network settings` it goes back to Off again.

No, the laptop does not have any hardware switch. Fn key does not work now for wifi, it only turns Bluetooth on and off.

Comment: Cannot post image, not having enough reputation.

Comment: Do you have a hardware wifi switch somewhere on the laptop?  Do you have a wifi button in your function key row?  Those must be enabled.

Comment: @Hydraxan14, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the list of available wireless networks, you have to:

1. Switch on `Connect to suggested open hotspots` (see the screenshot in question);
2. Click on Wifi icon in the right corner. Now you have your networks back.

After that the parameter from Step 1 can be turned off, networks will be listed normally after restarting Wifi.

P.S. I feel rather stupid at the moment. I thought that open hotspots are passwordless hotspots and so are presumably not very safe. So of course I've turned that off during installation.
Really hard to see any logic in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird.  I don't know why that option would change connecting to private hotspots.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution!
Install this "RF button driver" for Windows 8 64 bit:
https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/Others/Others_Dritek_2.02.2001.0803_W8x64_A.zip?acerid=634926875934121279&Step1=ULTRA-THIN&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%20S7-391&OS=8P1&LC=pl&BC=ACER&SC=EMEA_20

I've got Acer Aspire S7-391, and Windows 10 on it.
I couldn't switch the Wifi on, and my bluetooth didn't work, so I was searching for a solution but nothing did work. So I've thought, maybe other drivers from similar laptop will work, and on the Acer page I've checked the Windows 8 drivers (not the 8.1 ones), and there was an "RF button driver" (I thought about airplane mode button). After installing and rebooting it just works. Wifi is now ON, and Bluetooth works too!

Comment: This worked for me after updating windows 10 to 19042.

Comment: Worked for me on a PC I helped fix also. Thanks @Burza.